# From Color to Integer

Tags: processing

I'm having trouble understanding the following bit of code:

```
int pixel = img.pixels[i];

    // println("Working on pixel " + i + " out of " + img.pixels.length); 

    int red = (int) red(pixel);
    int green = (int) green(pixel);
    int blue = (int) blue(pixel);
```

I thought `img.pixels[]` gives a `color` value. So how is it being stored in an `int` and then being extracted from that by the `red()`, `blue()`, and `green()` functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[color in Processing](http://wiki.processing.org/w/What_is_a_color_in_Processing%3F) is stored as a plain 32-bit int. Each 8 bits (256 range) contains the value for ARGB (a = alpha), some ting like AAAARRRRGGGGBBBB, those when printed as an int gives weird results. red(), green() and blue() extracts the components from the int. [In the reference](http://processing.org/reference/red_.html) for them there is the alternate (faster) method using bit shift operations, for instance:

red(c) = c >> 16 & 0xFF;

check the wiki entrance linked above.

Comment: Quoting [Ben Fry](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596514556.do): "The `color` data type is simply an alias to `int`, and the two can be used interchangeably in the Processing syntax. Processing offers the color type because beginning programmers often find it confusing that pixel data is stored as an integer value."

Answer (score 0):

The colour value you are used to is the hexidecimal version of the colour where as the red green blue stands for RGB which is another format for colour as is CMYK

For example 0 red 0 green and 0 blue give black same as #000000 or 256 256 256 would give you white also #FFFFFF

I have also found some example JavaScript to convert rgb to hex. See below:

```js
function rgbToHex(R,G,B) { return toHex(R)+toHex(G)+toHex(B); }
function toHex(n) {
    n = parseInt(n,10);
    if (isNaN(n)) return "00";
    n = Math.max(0,Math.min(n,255));
    return "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt((n-n%16)/16)
        + "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt(n%16);
}
```